# Access javascript method inside different domain iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

I am looking for the way to call the javascript method inside with a different domain iframe.

For example, app.facebook.com contains iframe yyy.com inside.

I would like to call the yyyMethod() inside iframe yyy.com.

`app.facebook.com
|__iframe src="yyy.com" name="yyy"
   |__yyyMethod();`

- I tried window.frames["yyy"].contentWindow.yyyMethod(), but it return exception saying that we could not call method across domain.

Restrictions are

1) Adding/Modifying content in both app.facebook.com and yyy.com are prohibited, since I am not the site owner.

2) Execute from browser javascript console is one way to do, but I want to write plug the yyyMethod() caller with some javascipt code. Therefore, execute from browser javascript console may not be a good idea.

Any idea how to do this ? Not sure whether we can call from the chrome extension, bookmarklet, or something else ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Comment: @Roemer — No. That question is about *same* origin communication, not cross origin communication.

Comment: A browser extension might make this achievable (I don't know enough about them to say) but nothing else will.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Now I come up with the browser extension, and it works !